# V: iterate the characters (runes) of a string

Tags: vlang

According to my understanding, a string in V is wrapped around a byte array encoded as UTF-8. That way, iterating over all string elements returns the bytes:

```
fn main() {
    s := 'a string with äöü (umlauts)'
    println(s)
    for i := 0; i < s.len; i++ {
        print('-')
    }
    println('')
}
```

resulting in (note the longer underlining):

```
a string with äöü (umlauts)
------------------------------
```

How to get the length of the string in characters/runes? How to iterate over all characters/runes instead of bytes?

Answer (score 3):

You can call `.runes()` method on strings. This returns array of runes.

The following code demonstrates converting string to array of runes and then prints its type and lenght.

```
fn runes_demo(s string) {
    println(s)
    // Iterate over runes of string
    for _ in s.runes() {
        print('_')
    }
    println('')
    println('Return type of runes(): ${typeof(s.runes()).name}')
    println('Length of string in runes: $s.runes().len')
    println('')
}

fn main() {
    s := 'a string with äöü (umlauts)'
    runes_demo(s)
    t := 'hello there!'
    runes_demo(t)
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
a string with äöü (umlauts)
___________________________
Return type of runes(): []rune
Length of string in runes: 27

hello there!
____________
Return type of runes(): []rune
Length of string in runes: 12
```

Comment: To get back from an array of `rune` to a `string`, use the `string()` method. There's lots of similarly named functions and fields, so it may not be obvious this is the right one. To be clear: `assert s.runes().string() == s`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like one needs to use the `encoding.utf8` module:

```
import encoding.utf8

fn main() {
    s := 'a string with äöü (umlauts)'
    println(s)
    for i := 0; i < utf8.len(s); i++ {
        print('-')
    }
    println('')
}
```

Comment: The `rune` type is in the works right now. In the future this should be doable without importing a separate encoding module, but still WIP at this point unforunately.